# WPF- Translate Transform changing the Y axis with

Tags: wpf, binding

Im doing a image binding with a slider and the only thing that i want to do its move the Y axis down to up, but at this moment im moving the axis up to down. What can i do to invert the moving of the angle y?

This is the code:

```
<Image Margin="400,0,200,37" Source="/img/santa_claus.png" Stretch="Uniform" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="200" Height="195">
            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform  Y="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}" x:Name="transform"/>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
        
        <Slider Minimum="1" Maximum="100" x:Name="slider" Height="40" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Margin="226,392,200,12"  >
            <Slider.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform/>
                    <SkewTransform AngleY="-0.584"/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform Y="-1.482"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Slider.RenderTransform>
        </Slider>
```

I tryied diferent properties and changing the slider minimum to 100 and maximum to 1 but this nullifies the effect of the slider

Answer (score 0):

You may invert the direction of the translation by two "mirroring" ScaleTransforms with `ScaleY="-1"`.

```
<Image.RenderTransform>
    <TransformGroup>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
        <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
        <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
    </TransformGroup>
</Image.RenderTransform>
```

As a general note, do not use Margins for layout. Put the two elements in two rows of a Grid:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Grid.Row="0" Source="/img/santa_claus.png"
           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Stretch="Uniform" Width="200" Height="195">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
                <TranslateTransform Y="{Binding Value, ElementName=slider}"/>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleY="-1"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Slider Grid.Row="1" x:Name="slider"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Width="200" Margin="10"/>
</Grid>
```